# Socket security disregarding sniffing

Tags: sockets, ssl, sniffing

Supposing I am transmitting data over a socket connection, and I am not concerned with the data being sniffed or with someone replacing my packets with bad information - the data is encrypted and the client and server are the only ones capable of decrypting it.  Are there other security concerns with using ordinary sockets that are addressed by SSL/TLS?  Thank you.

Comment: "best practice" is to use SSL/TLS, not reinvent it.

Comment: The other concern that I can think of is authentication -- without that, there's no way for the client to verify that it is talking to the real server and not some man-in-the-middle hacker's proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there other security concerns with using ordinary sockets that are addressed by SSL/TLS?

Apart from simply encrypting the data SSL/TLS also protects against replay attacks, tampering with the encrypted packets (simple encryption like AES allows modification of encrypted packets which still decrypt successfully into different content) and man in the middle attacks (due to authentication of the peer). With the right key exchange it also provides forward resistance (protection against collecting data and decrypting later with the hacked secret). And properly done it can also resist against time based side channel attacks.

Just using AES with a shared secret or even worse some home made encryption does not protect against most of this. Encryption is not simple so please [don't roll your own](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) but use existing and established technologies.

Comment: Thank you, these all seem to be variations on man-in-the-middle attacks, which

Comment: Thank you, these all seem to be variations on man-in-the-middle attacks, I'm mostly wondering whether there's anything intrinsic to the socket implementation itself that poses a risk, for instance I expect that denial-of-service is probably still a concern.  If you disregard the content of the packets themselves because it's completely secure, are there other benefits to ssl/tls?  Does ssl/tls sit on top of a regular socket?

Comment: Okay, did a little more research and it looks like SSL is typically transmitted over TCP/UDP, which is what I was mostly trying to figure out.  Sorry my question was a little ambiguous, I'll mark your answer as correct for the information you provided.

Comment: @Gunnar: SSL/TLS cares only about the security of the data in transit, i.e. protection against sniffing and modification. It relies on a reliable underlying transport layer (typically TCP). It does not care about network level or application level denial of service - these are things which should be addressed at these levels themselves.